# where clause in mysql for update query gives syntax error for varchar primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I have a table 'PREFERENCES' having columns userid (integer), key (varchar(255)) and value (longtext). Columns (userid, key) is primary key. I have some data already in table. 
For example:

```
userid | key | value
12     | abc | testvalue12abc
12     | pqr | testvalue12pqr
13     | abc | testvalue13abc
14     | abc | testvalue14abc
14     | pqr | testvalue14pqr
14     | xyz | testvalue14xyz
```

When I run update query,

```
UPDATE PREFERENCES 
  SET value='somethingElse' 
WHERE userid=12 AND key='abc';
```

I get the syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid=12 AND key ='abc'' at line 1`.

I tried different combinations in where clause; It works fine when there is no varchar column in where clause. But it fails with syntax error when varchar column is used in where clause.

I am using mysql, server 5.1.49.

Comment: `KEY` is a [MySQL reserved keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) You must quote it in backticks to use it as a column or table identifier.

Comment: But your exact error message suggests a problem at `userid`. Make sure it has the correct whitespace before it as well and is _unquoted_.

Comment: Did you past the correct error message *`'userid=12 AND key ='abc'' at line 1`*

Comment: REFERENCES is a reserved word but this shouldn't affect your query.Your error message suggests that PREFERENCES is the problem,which is weird.Use back ticks for column and table names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
key
```

is a reserved keyword. enclose it in backticks as

```
UPDATE PREFERENCES SET value='somethingElse' WHERE userid=12 AND `key`='abc'
```